# Reset width to style sheet when jQuery returns false

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to set the width of the division in the footer. I wasn't the width to be calculated until the window reaches the certain size. However if I set the width using jQuery if I resize the window I have to refresh to get the width from the stylesheet. Is there any way to set it to do that when the jQuery width test returns false?

```
if ($("#container").width() > 553 ){
    $(".footer_links").css('width', $('.footer_div').innerWidth()-$('.footer_copyright').innerWidth()-$('.footer_design').innerWidth()-5);
}
```

Comment: `else { $(".footer_links").css('width', ''); }` but you'd have better to toggle a class

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't understand what you said 'but you'd have to better to toggle a class'. Could you clarify that please? It work's though. If you want to post it as an answer I'll up-vote it.

Comment: Set style in a css class then toggle it using for example [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/). Now if you want more specific help, you have to provide a MCVE

Comment: I understand you now. That seems sensible. I don't know what an MCVE is though.

Comment: If you put it ('MCVE') on google, what do you get?! :)

Comment: I get you. I'm okay now. Thanks for the help, I spent ages thinking it wasn't checking the size when it should and then suddenly realised it had no default (from the CSS) to find,
If I hadn't realised that I would have posted more.